# Function fires multiple times depending on how many times you open the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this modal to get the salary information, I have a lists of staff in a table

```
no         |         name           |        gender
1          |     test one           |           M
2          |     test two           |           F
```

The `name` is an anchor tag and it is clickable I have added a class named `btn-modal` which will fire the modal,

Here is the function:

```
$('.btn-modal').function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var obj = $(this);

  $.post('/function/getStaff', idx:obj.data('idx'), function(data) {
   if (data.ret) { 
     $('#myModal').modal('show');

     $('.modal-title').text(data.item.name);

     if (data.item.gender == 'MALE') {
        $('.btn-trigger').addClass('btn-male').removeClass('btn-female'); // Just in case there is a btn-female...
        $('.btn-male').function() {
           $.post('/function/male', {}, function(result) {
              if (result.ret) {
                  alert('This guys salary is: ' + result.salary);
              }
           }, 'json');
        });
     } else {
        $('.btn-trigger').addClass('btn-female').removeClass('btn-male'); // Just in case there is a btn-male...
        $('.btn-female').function() {
           $.post('/function/female', {}, function(result) {
              if (result.ret) {
                  alert('This ladies salary is: ' + result.salary);
              }
           }, 'json');
        });
     }
   }
  }, 'json');

});
```

If you open a modal once it will be fine, but If you close it and open it again either to another user or the same, and you click the button, It shows in the `Network` how many has been triggered, like if you open test one once and you open test two twice, It will show in the `Network`:

```
   male
   female
   female
```

How will I prevent this case? I tried adding `return false` after I open a modal but It is the same.

Comment: I would move `$('.btn-male').function()` and the female version out of the other function. Then it will stop.

Comment: So I will just make a `handler` for that functions? let me try thanks

Comment: Modal will be there if you close it too, i suggest you may use load your modal bidy html into it when showing modal

Comment: Your problem is that your are defining a new button handler each time the modal is opened. I think you should define two different buttons in your modal and define the onclick handlers on init. Then, when the modal is opened, just hide/show the corresponding button.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you sir, If you post that comment as answer I will gladly mark it as correct answer, It worked with just a little tweaking instead of just `$('.btn-male').click(function(){})` I used `$(document).on('click', '.btn-male', function(e){ }); ` and I put it outside the function